# Make webpack-dev-server to reuse existing opened tab

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, nodemon

I am trying to execute two different scripts using nodemon when it starts and when it restarts. The issue is that nodemon calls both `start` and `restart` events whenever it detects a change in a file.

So how can I execute two different scripts on start and restart. My purpose of doing so is because whenever nodemon picks up any change in a file, it restarts the `webpack-dev-server` and a new tab is opened in the browser instead of reusing the existing tab.

**package.json**

```
"start": "nodemon --watch app.js",
```

**nodemon.json**

```
{
   "events": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config=webpack.dev.config.js --open",
        "restart": "webpack-dev-server --config=webpack.dev.config.js"
   }
}
```

**webpack.dev.config.js**

```
.
.
devServer: {
    contentBase: "src",
    compress: true,
    stats: "minimal",
}
```

Comment: From *nodemon.json*, try removing `--open` flag.

Comment: Removing `--open` flag will disable automatic opening of the browser. My requirement is to open the browser tab on start and then reuse that tab on every restart of nodemon.

Comment: Removing the `--open` tag means that on restart, it will use the same tab, but when the server is initially started with an `npm start`, you must navigate to your localhost URL in the browser yourself. How can you get both the reuse and the initial open?

Comment: @KasparPoland Yes I realized its not possible. React too opens up a new tab in the browser when the same case scenario is tested.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with the help of `react-dev-utils`

set the `open` to `false` and manually trigger opening the browser with `react-dev-utils/openBrowser`

```
const openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser');

...
devServer: {
  port: 3000,
  open: false,
  onListening: function (devServer) {
    const { port } = devServer.server.address();
    openBrowser(`http://localhost:${port}`);
  },
},
...
```